# CTRL+clicking on function not navigates to function definition

Tags: c++, eclipse

Trying to get navigated when `ctrl+clicking` on function to is definition.

I have two C++ projects in my `Eclipse` workspace. First one - small and it works fine - I do `ctrl+click` on function and it navigates me to clicked function body.

Second project is large and `ctrl+click` not works. Maybe somehow it is related to fact that function is located in another source file from the same project.

How to make navigate to function definition by `ctrl+clicking` in second project?

UPD

Got workaround with open/close project. But why this happens at all?

Comment: Could it be that you ran into [this bug](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=517610#c5)?

Comment: I run Oxygen 2 and this bug too old.